# How to always request user to login google account when adding a new calendar event in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have tried with `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()` but it is not working after I hosted in IIS. I have also try to use `AppFlowMetadata` but it is not open a new tab to ask for login.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() is designed for installed applicaitons. The cosent screen is opened on the machine that the code is running on. This will work fine when testing but when hosted on IIS its gong to try to open the browser window on your web server.

You need different code if you want to use it for a web application have a look at [Web applications (ASP.NET Core 3)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3).

```
[GoogleScopedAuthorize(CalendarService.ScopeConstants.Calendar)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CalendarEventsList([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
{
    GoogleCredential cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
    var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = cred
    });
    var request = var request = service.Events.List("primary");       

    return View(request.Execute());
}
```

Comment: My web application is MVC .net and I have refer the guide on the https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3
It is still not able to redirect to the google login page

Comment: What happens when you do? is there an error?